# I’m Using NetBeans 11. But there is no Libraries category in the tree

Tags: java, dependencies

In order to follow a tutorial, I need to edit my Libraries settings. However when I right click my project and click properties, there is no Libraries category in the tree. I have done a bunch of searching and the results tell me that it just should be there by default.And  I know that I want to import the dependencies to the relevant dependency folder in the tree. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please what kind of project did you create? specifically the build system. The build system describes what tool NetBeans will use to manage(compiling & creating the jar file) your project.

The library menu appears when your project is based on ANT.

If the above is not helpful, kindly reply and describe the steps used in creating the project.

Comment: java with Maven project. I want to add iText library in the project

Comment: Then you must add this in the pom.xml file under the dependencies section

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies to the relevant dependency folder can ad by using pom.xml. just open the website mvnrepository.com and find the groupId,artifactId and version that jar file. then add it to pom file and compile.